# how can I evaluate a list of values in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I got a list such as

```
lista = {2x,3x+4,5,Cos[x]}
```

and then for some x value such as x = 3

how can I get the value of this list without actually assign 3 to x

Answer (score 3):

perhaps `ReplaceAll` could be an option, i.e.,

```
lista /. {x -> 3}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Also `Map[If[! NumberQ[#], N[#], #] &, lista /. {x -> 3}]`

Answer (score 0):

addendum to @ewcz

this evaluates the numerical Cosine at the same time.

```
lista /. x -> 3.0
```